# Cocotb and ghdl version mismatch?

Tags: ghdl, cocotb

when i run simple_dff cocotb example:

```
make SIM=ghdl TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl
```

i got following error:

```
loading VPI module 'C:/users/tomek/miniconda3/lib/site-packages/cocotb/libs/libcocotbvpi_ghdl.dll'
%1 is not Valid Win32 Application.

C:\eda\ghdl\bin\ghdl.exe:error: cannot load VPI module
```

my setup:

1. Windows 10 64-bit
2. GHDL 0.37 (v0.37) [Dunoon edition] Compiled with GNAT Version: 9.1.0
3. Python 3.7.7 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
4. conda 4.8.3
5. cocotb '1.4.0'

i guess something is wrong with 64 vs 32 bit libs...

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow those instructions: https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/wiki/Tier-2-Setup-Instructions#32-bit-python and https://docs.cocotb.org/en/stable/install.html#installation-of-prerequisites

Last time I have checked GHDL had issues to run on Windows (probably not related to cocotb) see: https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/pull/1644